# Which regions do twilio programmable chat support?

Tags: chat, twilio

I have built a chat app using twilio to completion but I have noticed initializing it is pretty slow on an EDGE connection, averaging to 10-15 seconds (Whatsapp and telegram takes about 3 seconds on the same connection).This is without having set any region via properties on the sdk. Am looking to achieving a snappy startup time like that of telegram/whatsapp.

To go around this issue I thought it might be network latency issue and I thought maybe setting different regions might resolving it. So far I have tried setting the regions provided here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/regions but am getting an error message `request to EMS service has failed unable to set FPA token` and error code 0.

Am in africa and my target audience will mostly be running on edge connections.

Please help resolve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio Programmable Chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) does not currently take a region option, like Twilio Client v1.4 does. In fact, when initializing a chat the only [option you can set right now is the logLevel](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/1.0.1/docs/Client.html#ClientOptions).

If you are interested in multi-region chat services, I suggest you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to register that this is an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks @philnash. I thought I could set a custom region mainly because that option exists in the current twilio chat sdk v1.04.  I did reach out to them yesterday, they told me they currently have one region i.e us1. Hopefully they will deploy to region soon.